# verilog if-else error message

Tags: if-statement, verilog

I have a problem with verilog if-else statement. I'm trying to make a digital clock and my tick_counter module code like this. I pointed to error line with comment line. I cant find the solve, please help me.

```
module tick_counter(
input clk,
input tick_in,
output [3:0] ssd_2, ssd_4,
output [2:0] ssd_3
);
reg [5:0] count1, count_next1;
reg [2:0] count2, count_next2;
reg [3:0] count3, count4, count_next3, count_next4;

always@(posedge clk)
    begin
        count1 <= count_next1;
        count2 <= count_next2;
        count3 <= count_next3;
        count4 <= count_next4;
    end
//next state logic
always@*
    begin
        if(tick_in)
            begin
                if(count1==6'b111100)               //second counter
                    begin
                        count_next1 = 6'b0;
                        count_next2 = count2 + 1'b1;
                    end
                else
                    count_next1 = count1 + 1'b1;
                if(count2==4'b1001)                 //minutes counter of LSB digit
                    begin
                        count_next2 = 4'b0000;
                        count_next3 = count3 + 1'b1;
                    end
                else
                    count_next2 = count2 + 1'b1;
                if(count3==3'b101)                  //minutes counter of MSB digit
                    begin
                        count_next3 = 3'b000;
                        count_next4 = count4 + 1'b1;
                    end
                else
                    count_next3 = count3 + 1'b1;
                if(count4==4'b1001)                 //counter hour
                    begin                 
                        count_next4 = 4'b0000;
                    end
                else
                    count_next4 = count4 + 1'b1;
        else                                        //---THE POINT OF ERROR------
            begin
                count_next1 = count1;
                count_next2 = count2;
                count_next3 = count3;
                count_next4 = count4;
            end
    end
end


    assign ssd_2 = count2;
    assign ssd_3 = count3;
    assign ssd_4 = count4;

endmodule
```

Comment: You have messed up using **begin and end**. You need think in terms of hardware (probably draw on a piece of paper) and rewrite it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course `endmodule` is missing. But this may be your typo mistake.

Proper indentation is greatly encouraged for large designs. Here, after indenting your code, I came to know that one `end` **after the** `else` part of `// counter hour` condition is missing. So, your main `if` condition's `end` is mis-placed. Just add `end` at the specified position and remove one `end` from the last of always block.

Kindly do proper indentation so that it becomes easy to debug.